# CATransition black shadow

Tags: ios, swift, catransition

What I am trying to do is to make a custom transition effect for my modal presented view controller (only for dismissing it). I just want it to look like the original but slower. The problem is I am getting a black shadow between my modal presented VC and the VC I want to go back.

That's my code so far:

```
let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.6
transition.type = kCATransitionReveal
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?